# Inline button in Telegram (using aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

How to make an inline button handler, so that pressing button 10000 will output 1, and pressing button 20000 will output 2 etc. I searched all over the Internet, everything they write does not work(

```
kb_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='10000', callback_data='ib_1')
kb_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='20000', callback_data='ib_2')
kb_3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='30000', callback_data='ib_3')
kb_4 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='40000', callback_data='ib_4')
kb_5 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='50000', callback_data='ib_5')
kb_6 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='60000', callback_data='ib_6')
kb_7 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='70000', callback_data='ib_7')
kb_8 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='80000', callback_data='ib_8')
kb_9 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='90000', callback_data='ib_9')
kb_10 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='100000', callback_data='ib_10')
kb_11 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='110000', callback_data='ib_11')
kb_12 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='120000', callback_data='ib_12')
kb_13 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='130000', callback_data='ib_13')

kb_money = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
kb_money.row(kb_1, kb_2, kb_3).row(kb_4, kb_5, kb_6).row(kb_7, kb_8, kb_9).row(kb_10, kb_11, kb_12).add(kb_13)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def all_client(message):
    if message.text == ' Покупка монет':
        await message.reply('Сколько монет ты хочешь?', reply_markup=kb_money)
```

I searched all over the Internet, everything they write does not work(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

cb_inline = CallbackData("post", 'action', "data")
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard= [
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='MyText', callback_data=cb_inline.new(action='myact', data='MyText')
        ]

@dp.callback_query_handler(cb_inline.filter(action='myact'))
async def choice_registr_method(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data):
    pass
```

)